Anaconda Jupyter Notebook show in and out keywords
I'm new to Jupyter Notebook and I'd like to show IN [] and Out [] keywords besides cells. How can I enable this?
as per attached image, it shown only cell number

I tired to open settings but I found nothing.

probably you would have to dig in source code to change it.

@furas Regarding your edit, please don't use code formatting for regular text

@wjandrea I know that there are some rules but frankly formatting as code makes it the most visible. I will try to reduce it next time.

@furas You could use bold instead, but for me, "Jupyter Notebook" is in the title and the tags and it's capitalized, so I think it's visible enough as is.

I think you are seeking NbClassic, right? What you describe as " IN [] and Out [] keywords besides cells." The old classic notebook interface has In[] and Out[] with the number of the cell in the brackets.  See here for more about old vs. current. For now you can optionally stick with NbClassic. Run conda install conda-forge::nbclassic in the Anaconda/conda prompt since your title indicates you are using Anaconda. I don't know if it adds it to the tiles in the Anaconda navigator, but jupyter nbclassic can launch.

 However, if you are actually new to this, I would caution you against this route. You will be better off in the long run just moving on and using the current Jupyter Notebook 7+ or JupyterLab interfaces as NbClassic will slowly become unusable with the packages and features you come to expect in your Jupyter Experience. (And back on the In[] and Out[] stuff, the attached first screenshot for the post here that I referenced for more information about the Jupyter interface ecosystem these days shows what I am trying to describe.)

Also if you meant Anaconda Cloud or Jupyter running on the Anaconda cloud, please update your title and text to clarify that. And then I don't think you have a choice about the interface because they use the current one. You can install the Anaconda Distribution if you want on your system to get what I was talking about.
